# Close Quarter Combat in Call of Duty Black Ops

Tags: nintendo-wii, call-of-duty-black-ops

In black ops, when getting in close to an enemy (ignoring the knife of course), is it better to ignore the scope and shoot from the hip?  Or is it better to scope in for the accuracy?  I was thinking I'm getting picked off because I'm going to scope and it slows me down, but I'm not sure if going to scope or not going to scope makes a difference...

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I think this depends less on the weapon and more on the situation and perk load out. For the sake of the point (IE: Close Quarters) I'm going to assume that you're just outside of knife range.

If you're sprinting around a corner or into a room your speed to get into ADS is going to be a tad slower. In this case, regardless of the weapon you're using, just hold down the fire button and spray until nothing is moving (obviously try to hit the baddie). IF you're using a sniper rifle you've got 2 options: Pull the trigger and hope to mighty Cthulhu that you hit, or swap to alternate weapon and start unloading.

If you're waiting around a corner and someone comes to you (assuming you aren't already in ADS gazing intently at the corner): With SMG if you have Sleight of Hand Pro (Puts you into ADS faster) go into ADS and unload, otherwise just got nuts again and start spraying. Same issue with sniper rifle too.

Lastly (and this is the method I strongly suggest), you can go into ADS WHILE shooting. This means you can start hip firing has you're going into ADS mode. In a CQC situation where I'm caught off guard by someone this is what I always default to. I start firing as I'm going into ADS. If you don't understand exactly what I mean here, create a private game and select an automatic gun. Hold down the trigger button and then go into ADS and back out of while still holding down the trigger. The gun will never stop firing and the accuracy improves when you move into ADS.

More often than not it'll just be better to start spraying if you can't get the knife off. Guns in Black Ops shoot fast enough and generally have enough accuracy that the first one shooting in a close up fight has the advantage.

Also, if this is a big problem you have while playing I highly suggest Sleight of Hand Pro. I use it religiously.

TL;DR:
Step 1: Shoot;
Step 2: ADS;
Step 3: ???;
Step 4: Profit;

Comment: Lag plays an un-invited role as well. Found that I am 300 milliseconds behind the action many times and by the time i pull the knife I am already dead even though the "baddie" is still beyond knife range.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the weapon. If you're using an SMG or something with a good bit of accuracy from the hip, then shooting from the hip is faster and accurate enough you're likely to hit your target.  If you're using an LMG or assault rifle, and you'd don't have the Steady Aim perk, you're probably better off going to aim down sights (ADS), because they'll be too inaccurate to hit anything.

EDIT: If you're using a sniper rifle, switching to pistol is always a better option than trying to quick scope or no scope an opponent. It'll work sometimes, but it's pure luck. The developers went to great length to try to prevent quick scoping for some reason. For instance a roughly 1.5 second delay in accuracy adjustment when going to scope on a sniper rifle.

Anyhow, Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Others have covered most of the important items. I'll just add that personally, my aiming seems slowed considerably when using ADS. Which is to say, if the opponent(s) is running around a lot, I might have trouble keeping a bead on him because the gun seems to move slower. When I'm shooting from the hip I can swivel and swing the gun around much faster.

I don't know enough of the mechanics to know if SMGs ignore this or if it's better/worse with some weapons more than others. If I have time and no one else chimes in then I'll try to test it tonight.

Comment: the ability to swing your gun in ADS is determined by the 'Mobility' attribute on the gun.  LMG's have very low mobility therefore swing much slower then SMG's

Comment: @Aardvark - Thanks. BTW, my nick for about the last 20 years was Aardvark. I was wondering who took it on here before I could ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the steady aim perk for "hip" shooting. Steady aim pro also lets you aim faster after sprinting.

Sleight of hand "pro" also has faster aim-down-sights which I think makes a difference for me as I also get picked off in fractions of a second slower than my opponent.

As sniper, use Ghost to stay off the radar so you can camp a while and pick off a few of the opposition and be less conspicuous. I always use claymores to set traps in case they do sneak up behind me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are within knife range just stab the guy, but if you are slightly further away then I suggest holding the fire button first to get a couple of shots on him and then hold the aim button and finish it, almost simultaneously that is, or have some fun and stick him with a semtex.